# How to code memory diagram?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was asked to code this memory diagram:

[image: memory diagram]

I was also given this struct:

```
struct product {
    char *name;
    double price;
    int stock_count;
};
typedef struct product PRODUCT;
```

I don't have to write the complete function just the required statements and write an array from the heap that can store two products, with the first product initialized as shown; i.e., with information about pies.

this is what I tried to do:
for item

```
PRODUCT item;
item->name = "bread"; //not sure if it's "bread" or &"bread"
item->price = 2.25;
item->stock_count = 45;
```

for the array from the heap that can store
two products:

```
PRODUCT *inventory, *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(PRODUCT)*2);
assert(p!=NULL);
inventory = p; //I've also read that the answer might be p = inventory not sure why though
```

but i'm not sure how to change the [0] show in the memory diagram where the name is "pie",price is 9.50 and stock_count is 7.

and if possible can someone write over the memory diagram for what would happen to it if

```
PRODUCT *p;
p = &inventory[1];
*p = item;
```

was executed?

Comment: "i'm not sure how to change the [0] show in the memory diagram". `p` is an array of `PRODUCT`. So `p[0]` is the first product. `p[0].name` is the name field of that product, etc.

Comment: It's `"bread"`, strings are already `(char*)`.

Comment: `p = malloc(sizeof(PRODUCT)*2);` is illegal code in C++.  Are you sure you are using a C++ compiler?

Comment: You do not need to use any dynamic allocation in this code (unless the diagram is specifically trying to imply that by omitting a name for the array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, it appears, you're on right way, and as per my understanding if you need only 1 `inventory`, you don't need a `p`, anyway. You can change your code like

```
PRODUCT *inventory = NULL;
inventory  = malloc(sizeof(PRODUCT)*2);
assert(inventory !=NULL);
```

and then, you can use the `inventory` to access the members, like

```
inventory[0].name = "pie";
inventory[0].price = 9.50;
inventory[0].stock_count = 7;
. . . . 
inventory[1].name 
inventory[1].price
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can just refer to the field inside of product/inventory:

```
inventory[0].name = "pie";
...
```

Alternatively you can temporary refer to that part:

```
PRODUCT *p = &inventory[0];
p->name = "pie";
...
```

What you could also do if using a recent compiler is declare it all at initialization: (you can't resize of free it anymore though)

```
PRODUCT inventory[2] = {
    { name: "pie", price: ..., stock_count: ... },
};
```